# React tabs - tab select call tab of other pages

Tags: reactjs

I have been using react tabs in two pages in my react application, where the second page is called inside first page. Whenever i select the tabs in the second page, it shows the tabpanel of the first page. Do we need to set any id or onclick event for this.

In Test.js page, using the tabs with below code

```
    <Tabs>
    <TabList>
           <Tab> Page 1 </Tab>
           <Tab> Page 2 </Tab> 
     </TabList>

     <TabPanel> <Page1 /></TabPanel>               
    <TabPanel> <Page2 /></TabPanel>               

     </Tabs>
```

In Page2.js, implemented vertical tab using "react-web-tabs" with below code,

```
<Tabs defaultTab="vertical-tab-one" vertical className="vertical-tabs">
  <TabList>
    <Tab tabFor="vertical-tab-one">Tab 1</Tab>
    <Tab tabFor="vertical-tab-two">Tab 2</Tab>

  </TabList>

  <TabPanel tabId="vertical-tab-one">
    <p>Tab 1 content</p>
  </TabPanel>

  <TabPanel tabId="vertical-tab-two">
    <p>Tab  2 content</p>
  </TabPanel>

</Tabs>
```

when i click on Tab2, it shows tab 2 content, however if i click on Tab1, it shows page 1(Test.js),instead of tab 1.

Comment: please post your code or an example in https://codesandbox.io/ or other sandbox. We need to see what you are doing.https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Added the sample code, as i just tried with sample available.

Answer (score 0):

There is a conflict between the two different libraries. I would just choose 1 of them. (react-tabs can go vertical). Here are some examples showing how to go vertical with react-tabs:
(Link has two examples, one with content beneath, one beside)
https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-aryabhata-6gxc6?file=/src/index.js

```
import { Tab, Tabs, TabList, TabPanel } from "react-tabs";
import styled from "styled-components";
import React from "react";

    const StyledTab = styled.div`
      ul {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        border: none;
      }
      .react-tabs__tab {
        border: none;
        :hover {
          background: blue;
        }
      }
    `;
    const Page2 = props => {
      return (
        <StyledTab>
          <Tabs>
            <TabList>
              <Tab>Title 1</Tab>
              <Tab>Title 2</Tab>
            </TabList>

            <TabPanel>
              <h2>Any content 1</h2>
            </TabPanel>
            <TabPanel>
              <h2>Any content 2</h2>
            </TabPanel>
          </Tabs>
        </StyledTab>
      );
    };
    export default Page2;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I chose the react-web-tabs to display vertical tabs,since it was not working with react-tabs.Can you please explain about hidden prop. I didn't get, how it will resolve this issue.

Comment: updated the answer with an example using react-tabs and making it vertical.

Comment: No problem, if it works for you, please mark it as the answer.  If you need any help, just shoot me a msg and I can help you out.